# Did Gandalf ever have a romantic partner or a spouse?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings, the-hobbit, gandalf

Inspired by [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/110812/how-does-interspecies-reproduction-work-in-the-lord-of-the-rings-universe) (about interspecies pairings on the LOTR universe), **I was wondering whether *Gandalf* ever had a romantic partner or spouse?**

I've read the books several times, but I don't remember ever this being mentioned or even hinted at. Certainly in the movies (and especially in the Hobbit trilogy) one may detect a not-so-subtle hint of affection between Gandalf and Galadriel that goes beyond mere friendship but I would attribute that to Peter Jackson's vision of the mythology.

In any case, for this question I'm only interested in the books and any letters that Tolkien may have written.

Comment: No, not in Tolkien's works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only example any Maia having a spouse or even romantic relationship, is Melian, who married the elven king Elu Thingol and became queen of Doriath in the First Age.  There were marriages among the Valar but nothing recorded for the Maiar, with themselves or other races, with that one exception.

Comment: There was also the unrequited love of the moon for the sun.

Comment: If you accept the theory, also Tom Bombadil and Goldberry. And in some early versions of the Silmarillion, some Maiar (e.g. Fionwë > Eonwë) were "Children of the Valar".

Comment: Osse, lord of the sea, vassal of ulmo, had another maia as wife.