# Are there half-dwarves in Middle Earth?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, dwarves

Inspired by [this question/answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/100403/14714)

According to the answer, `The Lord of the Rings has both half-elves and half-orcs, but no half-dwarves or half-hobbits`.

Is there any example in LOTR of half-dwarves? If not, is there any clear reason? For example, is it because some sort of genetic incompatibility, or is it more because no proper dwarf would ever be caught copulating with a stinking tree-hugging elf?

Comment: The accepted answer to the dupe question addresses this - *"There are no dwarf-elf romances or reproduction in canon (real canon, not those damn films)."*

Comment: Also a dupe of [Tauriel and Kili relationship: Can a dwarf and an elf reproduce?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/78979/tauriel-and-kili-relationship-can-a-dwarf-and-an-elf-reproduce)

Comment: Ahh, my apologies. Should I delete the question or just leave it?

Comment: [Is it encouraged to delete your own questions if they have possible duplicates?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7943/is-it-encouraged-to-delete-your-own-questions-if-they-have-possible-duplicates) - Short answer no. Your question acts as google-bait to lead people to the dupe.